# Can't get this mouse detection code to work reliably... any ideas?

Tags: c#, wpf

This code is just POC, "written in WPF", but pretty much the same thing would apply to Winforms if you change the event handlers to winforms ones... just trying to get the logic down and then I'll productionalize it.

What I'm trying to do is detect a change in mouse direction for a drag operation. So for example, click & hold on the client area of the form and move the mouse to the right, now move it to the left... that would be a direction change. Same thing obviously left <-> right, right <-> left, up <-> down, down <-> up... diagonal to the upper right <-> diagonal to the lower left, etc.

I've tried a few various concepts and the one I have no seems to work the best, but its still kinda unreliable... I get some false positives and some misses. The idea this code is doing is to save up 10 points of mouse moves and then calculate the angle of the line between the first and last point and then if I get the next segment in *ROUGHLY* the opposite direction, that would be a change. It kinda / sorta works, but I'd put the reliability at like 75%. The unreliability seems to be if you do something like move to the upper left diagonal and then go back and forth up and down, it won't detect the up down direction changes reliably.

I'm not married to the angle idea... its just what I've gotten to work best so far.. here is the minimal code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MouseLeftButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            MouseLeftButtonUp += MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            MouseMove += MainWindow_MouseMove;
        }

        Point _pt;
        List<Point> lst = new List<Point>();
        double? _d = null;

        void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse.Captured == this)
            {
                lst.Add(e.GetPosition(this));

                if (lst.Count >= 10)
                {
                    double dX = lst[lst.Count - 1].X - lst[0].X;
                    double dY = lst[lst.Count - 1].Y - lst[1].Y;

                    double dAngle = Math.Atan2(dY, dX) * 180 / Math.PI;

                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GOT ANGLE: " + dAngle);

                    if (!_d.HasValue)
                    {
                        _d = dAngle;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Math.Abs(dAngle - _d.Value));

                        if (Math.Abs(dAngle - _d.Value) >= 160.0 && Math.Abs(dAngle - _d.Value) <= 200)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " DIRECTION CHANGE!");
                            _d = dAngle;
                        }

                        _d = dAngle;
                    }

                    lst.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        void MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        void MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            lst.Clear();
            _d = null;
            _pt = e.GetPosition(this);
            CaptureMouse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow... how would you detect the direction using two points side by side? Wouldn't you get either a horizontal line, a vertical line or a "45 degree" line? Also, from my experimentation, I've notice that due to the obvious nature of a person moving the mouse, there is "noise" in the data. One other gotcha... is that when you are moving diagonally, you aren't getting both the X & Y change in the same event always... sometimes it comes as 2+.

Comment: I think you should do your comparisons against your variable _pt at some point in time since this is the origin of your drag and drop request and I don't see it used in your calculations.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my original question but I wasn't sure why you would capture the last 10 movements then only do comparisons against it (which is effectively what you're doing since you only do your calculations against the start point of the last 10 and the most current location. In theory, you could change direction at point 0 after you cleared the list and the comparison would be valid as long as the change continued in the same direction for the duration of the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the following code

```
double dX = lst[lst.Count - 1].X - lst[0].X;
double dY = lst[lst.Count - 1].Y - lst[1].Y;
```

should be changed to:

```
double dX = lst[lst.Count - 1].X - _pt.X;
double dY = lst[lst.Count - 1].Y - _pt.Y;
```

My reasoning is this: You are reading in the last 10 positions from the mouse movement so as an example (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),(0,10)

Then you run your comparison and clear the list. However if the cursor is moving in the opposite direction when the list is cleared, then the detection would go unnoticed since it's still sequential:
(0,10),(0,9),(0,8),(0,7),(0,6),(0,5),(0,4),(0,3),(0,2),(0,1)

Comment: Actually this is not the answer. I just ran this in a console app and the change was detected when I went sequential on one axis (the y in this case). When I went sequentially, on both axis then reversed, the direction was missed. And this was true in both the snippets provided above. It may have to do with the function for detecting change but my trig is really rusty so I can be of no help

Comment: I'm not calculating the angle against _pt because that is the click down point. So if I click down at 0,0 and then move to 100,0, it wouldn't detect a direction change until it crossed back over 0,0 into -1,0 at least.